# why does this png have a white border

Tags: html, css, png

This png-24 image looks like its color extends completely to the edge of its 302 × 354 dimensions:
[image: png]
However, when I put it in a td and send it in an email, I get something like this:
[image: png in email]

html table:

```
    <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:top; border:1px solid #e6e6e6; background-color:#f0f1f2;">
        <img src="email_img.png" height="177px" alt="Sample image" />
    </td>
```

Screenshot is from gmail. Have not looked at other email clients though. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but you have a rowspan, so the content in the other rows is taking up too much vertical height? Can't see the rest of the content, so I don't know if the image height is taller and defines the height or if it's the other way around.

Comment: @lewiguez seems that the image is controlling the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because each email client has it's own rendering engine i.e. Outlook vs someother desktop email client. To get around this you would need to do a LOT of cross client testing and only use inline styles that they all 'like'

OR

If you are seeing this in i.e. gmail then you probably have gmails stylesheet cascading down and affecting your DOM elements. To get around this you need to define a style for the table (inline as it is email OR referencing a stylesheet on your server though it is probably that the web based client will strip everything outside of body)

Comment: would it be hacky just add a background color to the cell that contains the image that's the same as the background color of the image?

Comment: I would say yes because if you don't fix it properly then your dimensions will be out in other places ... :]

Answer (score 0):

For email always use `<img src="[img url]"height="[img height]" width="[img width]" style="display:inline-block;" border="0">` Without that some e-mail clients will add a border

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the `img`.

Either set the CSS to `display:block` or `vertical-align:top`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:top; border:1px solid #e6e6e6; background-color:#f0f1f2;" cellpadding="0">
    <img src="email_img.png" height="177px" alt="Sample image" />
</td>
```

Try adjusting the cellpadding. You do want to set a height on that image too, emails are a huge pain in the ass in my opinion but you'll find a lot less headaches if you specify everything and leave nothing up to the individual HTML rendering engines.